# Speed control not slowing my video in the video editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor

So I started editing my YT videos in **Blender VSE**. I was trying to slow the strip down, I visited the blender documentation to see how to slow strip down and followed the steps but was disappointed to see that the speed controller wasn't working with any value less than 1, so in other words it wasn't letting me slow the clip by any value less than 1.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

To learn about the various Speed Strip options, read/watch this post:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/185894/37272